# Are Functions special in CDI w.r.t. @Inject vs BeanManager.getBeans(Function.class)?

Tags: cdi, wildfly-swarm, weld2

I have two classes, which I wish to inject:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BeanThing {
    public String apply(String s) {
       return "bt(" + s + ")";
    }
}
```

and

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ClassFunction implements Function<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        return "cf(" + s + ")";
    }
}
```

When I try and use them elsewhere I get different behaviour:

```
    Set<Bean<?>> functions = beanManager.getBeans(Function.class);
    for (Bean<?> untyped : functions) {
        Bean<Function<String, String>> typed = (Bean<Function<String, String>>) untyped;
        Function<String, String> function = beanManager.getContext(typed.getScope()).get(typed, beanManager.createCreationalContext(typed));
        System.err.println(function.apply("beanManager"));
    }

    Set<Bean<?>> beanThings = beanManager.getBeans(BeanThing.class);
    for (Bean<?> untyped : beanThings) {
        Bean<BeanThing> typed = (Bean<BeanThing>) untyped;
        BeanThing beanThing = beanManager.getContext(typed.getScope()).get(typed, beanManager.createCreationalContext(typed));
        System.err.println(beanThing.apply("beanManager"));
    }

    System.err.println(injectedFunction.apply("injected"));
    System.err.println(beanThing.apply("injected"));
    System.err.println("injectedFunction is a function: " + (injectedFunction instanceof Function));
```

my output is:

```
bt(beanManager)
cf(injected)
bt(injected)
injectedFunction is a function: true
```

which is one fewer lines than I expect.

Could someone explain what going on here?

Solution, thanks to Siliarus for setting me off down the right path:

```
Set<Bean<?>> functions = beanManager.getBeans(new ParameterizedType() {

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[]{new WildcardType() {...}, new WildcardType() {...};
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return Function.class;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your sample correctly what you are missing is the first line - output from the `Function` when obtained via `BeanManager`.

My guess is, that the `Set<Bean<?>> functions` is empty. The reason for that are **generics**. `Function` is a generic type and methods on `BeanManager` are not really good with that. CDI spec defines [Typesafe resolution for parameterized types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#assignable_parameters) pretty well (although it takes some reading).

In short, your bean of type `Function<String, String>` won't be assignable to just raw `Function.class`, which you pass to `BeanManager` method.

As a side note, if you wish to instantiate parametrized types on-the-fly, you can always use [`Instance<T>`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#programmatic_lookup), which supports the use of [`TypeLiteral`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#annotationliteral_typeliteral) - a special construct which holds not only the raw type, but also information about the actual parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I'm asking the BeanManager because I want to know about the other Qualifiers on the bean, as I'm sure you guessed given the types involved this eventually will be an Producer returning a lambda rather than a dedicated Class.

I am still unsure how to ask the bean manager for Function<?,?>?

Comment: So by giving the BM some useful Type info it was fine. I just needed to be very explicit, ParametrizedType, with Two WildcardTypes as the argumentTypes.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! :)